# Smoking and Pill icon

Tags: html, css, icons, font-awesome, glyphicons

I want to add a smoking and pill icon in my buttons. Font awesome and bootstrap apparently don't have these icons.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [Unicodes](http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html). But it may look different in some older browsers.

```css
span{
font-size:20px;
}
```

```html
<span><span>
<br>
<span><span>
```

Comment: Can you give just the cigarette sign without the ban sign? May I ask how did you do this? This helped, so thank you!

Comment: @SteveDoson this is not Cross-browser solution)

Comment: this is html symbol . full symbol reference : https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_utf8.asp

Comment: You can also use Unicodes. But it may look different in some older browsers. 
 http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html

Comment: I found the smoking icon and added the code

Answer (score 0):

you can create your own font from svg icon

there is a lot of website where you online can create them

https://icomoon.io/app/#/select - for example

Comment: or just create svg or(2x png) and set as bg for your block

if you create 2x size png (for example 80x80 and put it to container 40x40) and set background-size: cover it will be nice at retina display

hope it will help you

Comment: https://glyphter.com/

Comment: thanks for the idea, I used icons8. There they even generate the html code with the cdn.